# Laravel Routing Problems

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I am trying to do routing in Laravel, but it does not work well for me :( Here is my code:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});

Route::get('login', function() {
    return view('login');
});
```

I have login.blade.php in my views folder. I don't know, what is wrong. Thanks for help :P

Comment: what is the error output ?

Comment: What's not working? Do you see an error message, a blank page, what? You're code looks ok otherwise.

Comment: I can see this: Not Found

The requested URL /kubirovaciTabulky/public/login was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your route is perfect. The problem you've been with your link.

```
localhost/kubirovaciTabulky/public/index.php/login
```

Possible solution: Create a virtual host.